# RESTful Authorization check

Tags: token, access-token, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

I have a RESTful web application, would like to implement a token based authentication. I was able to issue a token intercepting a request with a filter class as follows:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    JpaConfiguration jpaConfiguration;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // disable caching
        http.headers().cacheControl();          
        http.csrf().disable() // disable csrf for our requests.
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // Here the login requests is filtered
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // Much probably here I have to filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header,
            // here i just add a commented block with teh name of the Filter
                //.addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                ;
            }
    }
```

The JWTLoginFilter class looks like this:

```
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;
public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
     super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
     setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
     tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService();
}

 @Override
 public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
 throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
     ServletInputStream inputStream = httpServletRequest.getInputStream();
     httpServletRequest.getCharacterEncoding();

     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     AccountCredentials credentials = mapper.readValue(inputStream, AccountCredentials.class);

     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
     return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
 }
 @Override
 protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication)
 throws IOException, ServletException {
     String name = authentication.getName();
     tokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, name);
     }
}
```

Which class should extend the `JWTAuthenticationFilter` in order to intercept the request?

Is it still the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` class?

Is there a better way to develop token based authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally find a solution:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        try{
            ...

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
            chain.doFilter(servletRequest, response);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `JWTAuthenticationFilter` extends a `GenericFilterBean` class and must implement a spring security Filter, the method doFilter does the trick.

NOTE: you have to call the `doFilter` method from `FilterChain` class otherwhise you newer come to the endpoint, I got crazy on that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why JWTLoginFilter was used. I am doing on a project that developing a RESTful secured by OAuth2. In overview, requester must pass access token together with the REST API for authorization.

Below are examples that might be a reference

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class Oauth2AuthConfiguration implements ResourceServerConfigurer {
      @Autowired
      private OAuth2RemoteTokenServices tokenServices;

      @Override
      public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
          resources.tokenServices(tokenServices);
      }

      @Override
      public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
         httpSecurity.exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(new PPDAccessDeniedHandler())
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new PPDAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(POST, "/api/test").hasAuthority("PARTNER");
      }
}
```

OAuth2RemoteTokenServices.java

```
public class OAuth2RemoteTokenServices implements ResourceServerTokenServices{
    //implement how you can validate token here
    // reference: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices
}
```